# Google CSE: breaks when I search with special characters like "é"

Tags: html, forms, google-custom-search

we have installed the custom search engine on our website.
It works fine until we try to search with accentuated letters.
Since the website is in french, it kinda needs to work...

So that if I search:
"poupee" -- works fine
"poupee!" -- works fine too
"poupée" -- doesn't work. The actual call to search on google is not even called

You can test it here:
poupée -- doesn't work:
http://www.ckoi.com/recherche.php?q=poup%E9e&sa=&cx=012997159615660210985%3Ask7xitg5ylq&cof=FORID%3A11&ie=ISO-8859-15&oe=ISO-8859-1&siteurl=www.ckoi.com%2F&ref=&ss=1994j797008j8

poupee -- works:
http://www.ckoi.com/recherche.php?q=poupee&sa=&cx=012997159615660210985%3Ask7xitg5ylq&cof=FORID%3A11&ie=ISO-8859-15&oe=ISO-8859-1&siteurl=www.ckoi.com%2F&ref=&ss=776j143854j6

poupee! -- works:
http://www.ckoi.com/recherche.php?q=poupee!&sa=&cx=012997159615660210985%3Ask7xitg5ylq&cof=FORID%3A11&ie=ISO-8859-15&oe=ISO-8859-1&siteurl=www.ckoi.com%2F&ref=&ss=2272j1680258j8

And the custom engine has been set to be in french.

----- EDIT:
Here is the html form, which I switched back to ISO-8859-1 (the encoding of my website)

```
<div class="search-form">           
    <form class="search-wrapper cf" action="/recherche.php" id="cse-search-box">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Rechercher des extraits audio, articles..." name="q" />
        <button type="submit" class="search-button" name="sa"><i class="icon ion-search"></i></button>
        <input type="hidden" name="cx" value="012997159615660210985:sk7xitg5ylq" />
        <input type="hidden" name="cof" value="FORID:11" />
        <input type="hidden" name="ie" value="ISO-8859-1" original_value="ISO-8859-1" /> <!--value="ISO-8859-15"-->
        <input type="hidden" name="oe" value="ISO-8859-1" original_value="ISO-8859-1" /><!--value="ISO-8859-1"-->
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/cse/brand?form=cse-search-box&lang=fr"></script>
</div>
```

Anyone knows what I need to do?

Comment: That codepage could be the problem. That ie parameter points to latin-9 while oe points to latin-1. Not sure what they do but I would replace it with utf-8.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
I tried changing the lines ie and oe to be: 
<input type="hidden" name="ie" value="UTF-8" original_value="UTF-8" />
<input type="hidden" name="oe" value="UTF-8" original_value="UTF-8" />
but the results do not show either.
And we use ISO-8859-1 as the encoding on our pages normally.

Comment: You also need to change the encoding of the page itself. E.g. with a meta tag.

Comment: I changed the encoding to utf-8 but no luck there: http://www.ckoi.com/recherche.php?q=poup%E9e&sa=&cx=012997159615660210985%3Ask7xitg5ylq&cof=FORID%3A11&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&siteurl=www.ckoi.com%2F&ref=&ss=3364j1341670j12  
I also notice that on a "good" request, there is call of the form: http://www.google.com/cse?q=poupee&... Which is not there when I try with accentuated letters (like é).

Comment: you have still an encoding issue. check this link: http://www.ckoi.com/recherche.php?q=poup%C3%A9e&sa=&cx=012997159615660210985%3Ask7xitg5ylq&cof=FORID%3A11&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&siteurl=www.ckoi.com%2F&ref=&ss=3364j1341670j12
I just replaced the latin encoded é=%E9 by a proper utf-8 encoded é=%C3%A9 and it works fine. I guess you have still a problem with the html form. show that code ;-)

Comment: @rekire: Thanks for your help! I added the form. Thanks to you, I can see that the problem is how the query is encoded. Nonetheless, I can't switch the whole website to UT8 encoding. Moreover, the CSE docs says I should specify the enconding only if it's not UTF-8, which I did. I'm now tempted to just create my own form that would translate to google's query form, but that would be harder to maintain. Hum...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just define the encoding for that form (`accept-charset="utf-8"`) that should work fine.

```html
<div class="search-form">           
    <form class="search-wrapper cf" action="/recherche.php" id="cse-search-box" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Rechercher des extraits audio, articles..." name="q" />
        <button type="submit" class="search-button" name="sa"><i class="icon ion-search"></i></button>
        <input type="hidden" name="cx" value="012997159615660210985:sk7xitg5ylq" />
        <input type="hidden" name="cof" value="FORID:11" />
        <input type="hidden" name="ie" value="utf-8" />
        <input type="hidden" name="oe" value="utf-8" />
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/cse/brand?form=cse-search-box&lang=fr"></script>
</div>
```

With this jsfiddle you can check it live: http://jsfiddle.net/129d21nv/

However on that site you have still an encoding problem, but this is IMHO a diffrent problem.

Comment: OMG! That's it! Just by setting the accept-charset="utf-8" on the form, it fixed the issue! And no matter if I put ISO-8859-1 or UTF-8 for ie and oe, both worked! Thanks! You're a saver!

Comment: You should reply faster to comments ;-) You are welcome!

Comment: for me it i still not working :( some browsers do, other not